# Heavy Wordpress MySQL query, please help me find it and optimise it

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website up and running that is reasonably popular but over the last couple of days my performance has degraded terribly.

I have installed Jet Profiler and have been monitoring the MySQL database to see if I can find something wrong and this one query is consistently the worst offender.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.ID ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

My first guess would be to remove the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS function and change the * to be specific fields only but I can't find what is calling this query.

How would I find out which php file is calling this?

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: It's the latest version 2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was that a plug in called TDO Mini Forms was badly coded and destroying my database.

So if you ever have this problem and have that plug in I strongly recommend removing it. It doesn't appear to even exist as a valid option in the plugin database anymore

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance that's your front page. I assume you've installed caching in front of WordPress, either using [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) or something else ([nginx](http://nginx.org/), [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), etc). If not, you shouldn't be looking at the database. [Caching is critical for WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching).

Comment: I am using WP Super Cache and am now swapping that for W3 Total Cache but I am still getting the same problems with instability

The site can be found here if it helps www.lazygamer.co.za

Comment: I got back a 406 response code when I access that page a couple times. That might be preventing your page from being cached. Your page should be returning a 200 response code when everything goes right.

Comment: That would explain the behaviour I am seeing. What tool did you use to check the response codes?

Comment: `curl -D - -o /dev/null http://www.lazygamer.co.za` will show just the headers returned from the request

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at these two issues posted on their tracker:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10469

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12557

(Update: Added a link)

Comment: Thanks I did see this but all they seem to be saying is that this is wrong but they aren't fixing it yet. I am trying to find this specific query from somewhere to fix it or optimise it